# How to rediect to redirect url in Django, Python, Keycloak

Tags: python, django, keycloak

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ResetCredential(RedirectView):
    url = '/oidc/logout'    #logout method in keycloak
    def get(self, request):
        return redirect('https://docs.djangoproject.com/')
```

I want to call first this < url = '/oidc/logout' > because I want to logout first and then https://docs.djangoproject.com/

URL:

```
path('oidc/', include('keycloak_oidc.urls')),
```

Comment: Can you please mention which third-party tool did you use to integrate keycloak in your django project? Adding more information will help understand question better.

Comment: ```path('oidc/', include('keycloak_oidc.urls'))```
that is third party authentication keycloack_oidc

Answer (score 1):

When using the standard Django authentication, or [a library to integrate Keycloak](https://django-keycloak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can [log out the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) using an imported functon, example code from the documentation:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ResetCredential(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('https://docs.djangoproject.com/')
```

The [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout) say

> For other browser applications, you can redirect the browser to http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri, which logs you out if you have an SSO session with your browser.

In your case pass `https://docs.djangoproject.com/` (encoded) as the `encodedRedirectUri` parameter.

Comment: It is not working because we use keyclock authentication

Comment: @KetanMangukiya - sorry, I missed your question tag. It would be good to mention Keycloak in the question :) Are you using a library to help integrate keycloak in to Django? Such as [django-keycloak](https://django-keycloak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Keycloak but I have a suggestion based on the docs, I've updated my answer.